# Google Drive List Search not working as expected

Tags: list, google-drive-api

I am able to fetch Google drive files list by using below code:

```
 fields: "nextPageToken,files,kind,incompleteSearch",
```

here is an excerpt of data:

```
"permissions": [
                {
                    "kind": "drive#permission",
                    "id": "04794351729057901443",
                    "type": "user",
                    "emailAddress": "****@gmail.com",
                    "role": "writer",
                    "displayName": "****** ******",
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "kind": "drive#permission",
                    "id": "15825279250807914438i",
                    "type": "user",
                    "emailAddress": "****@somedomain.com",
                    "role": "writer",
                    "deleted": false
                },
                {
                    "kind": "drive#permission",
                    "id": "05778350231604601914",
                    "type": "user",
                    "emailAddress": "*****@*****.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                    "role": "owner",
                    "displayName": "*****@******.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                    "deleted": false
                }
            ],
```

I wish to narrow my search based on user permissions.

Here is the code i am using to filter.

```
function listFolderInGoogleDrive() {
     drive.files.list(
      {
    q: "'****@somedomain.com' in writers",
    fields: "nextPageToken,files,kind,incompleteSearch",
    spaces: 'drive',
      
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data.files));
        listToShow = res.data
        const files = res.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
          console.log("Files:");
          files.map((file) => {            
            console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("No files found.");
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I get no result. It filters everything out.

```
{"kind":"drive#fileList","incompleteSearch":false,"files":[]}
```

I am using similar syntax as recommended.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded, there are bugs in Google Drive List Search algorithm and it is slow as well. It is better to pull all the data and add your own search engine to make it a more flexible and faster.

I used this simple 4 lines of code that rescued me from a week of R&D on google documentation to get appropriate search result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < JoSearch.length; i++) {
      if (JSON.stringify(JoSearch[i]).toLowerCase().search(criteria.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          outputText.push(JoSearch[i])
      }  
}
```